# How to perform linear discriminant analysis (LDA)?

Tags: matlab, lda

I have a set data (100, 61), 100 is sampling point(observation), 61 is features. I have done data reducement using PCA before, but the plot of coeff 1 and 2 (PCA 1 and 2) has many overlap data. Hence I want to try LDA which has an euclidean distance between classes that expected can perform better than PCA. But I have difficulties to perform LDA using fisheriris function, I refer to this link

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/create-and-visualize-discriminant-analysis-classifier.html

but those only plot two feature (PL and PW). But in my case I need to plot 61 features in the same plot as perform in PCA as coeff1/coeff2. How do I can perform data projection using LDA(which considering euclidean distance) ?

Comment: Unclear what exactly you're asking. If it helps there's an LDA function available on the MathWorks File Exchange [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45006-fda-lda-multiclass).

Comment: Are you asking how to visualize 61-dimensional data?

Comment: I want to perform the similar thing as PCA can be done but in this case by using LDA, plot the first and second principal component from 100 data, each data has 61 measurement/feature.